# When has my async function finished

Tags: c#, function, asynchronous, bitmap, void

I have coded a C# `void` `async` function that takes the following parameters:

1. A `string` url
2. A `Bitmap` object

The function then retrieves the url from a file cache, memory cache or downloads the url from a website asynchronously.

My question is this: How can I be informed of when the `Bitmap` object has been populated with an image so that I can then use this `Bitmap` image in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way of knowing when *async void* method completes. Change the return type of the method from `void` to `Task`. Return the task indicating when the operation will complete.

Then it is simple to wait for the `Task` to complete in client code. As soon as the `Task` completes you can use your `Bitmap`.

If you're downloading a bitmap from some source, you should ideally return `Task<Bitmap>` rather than passing `Bitmap` as parameter and modifying it. (Disregard it if I understand something wrong).

Answer (score 1):

If you want check when the Bitmap is ready the easiest way is transform your method in something like this:

```
async Task<bool> myMethod(myParamter) {

    //DO Something
    return true;

}
```

And then call the method in the following way

```
bool isReady = await myMethod(...)
```

You have also have to change the method's signature where you call `myMethod` adding async

An improved version:

```
Task<bool> pendingDownload = null;

private async void mainMethod(...) {
    if(pendingDownload != null) {
        MessageBox.Show("Image is not ready!");
        return;
    }
    try{
        pendingDownload = myMethod(...);
        bool isReady = await  pendingDownload;
        MessageBox.Show("Bitmap downloaded");
    } catch(Exception e) {
         MessageBox.Show("Error in downloading image: " + ex.Message);
    }
    pendingDownload = null;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `bool` if you never return any other value than `true`?

Comment: It's just an example normally when you download a file you can have two state: true file downloaded, false some error and download is stopped

Comment: @Tinwor That should be conveyed via `Exception`.